# SWIG c# with a virtual pure interface

Tags: c#, c++, swig

I'am trying to wrap a C++ virtual pure interface into c# using SWIG.
Here is my dll C++ interface:

```
class EXPORT FeatureItf
{
protected:
    virtual ~FeatureItf() { }
public:
    virtual void PrintMe() = 0;
    virtual void Delete() = 0;
};

bool EXPORT FeatureItfCreator(FeatureItf*& feat);
```

For a C++ user linking the dll, API is simple :

```
FeatureItf* feat = nullptr;
FeatureItfCreator(feat); // will allocate feat
feat->PrintMe();
feat->Delete();
```

How to wrap the `FeatureItf` class into a c# class using SWIG ?
In particular to manage the *& in creator function and the construction on the c# object.

Comment: “What is the best way” is opinion-based.  Voting to close.

Comment: @HenriMenke I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine :

```
%include swigtype_inout.i
%apply SWIGTYPE *& OUTPUT { SWIGTYPE *& }
```